# Dynamically adding news to feed

Tags: php, html, wordpress, dynamic, feed

I'm running a Wordpress website and I have a `<marquee>` on the front page that runs the news.

Is it possible to have it dynamically generate the news? What do I mean by that?

Would it be possible to make it so that whenever a new post is made with a category of "News", it will automatically be fed into the `<marquee>` on the front page, along with the five older news posts, such that the six most recent news posts are being `<marqueed>` in the front page, and so that the user doesn't have to go into the html code to manually add in entries.

Is this too far out of reach? Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Amit

Comment: I thought `<marquee>` was deprecated?

Comment: Hm, maybe? Is there an alternative? A client wants "running news" for some god-forsaken reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, if I think about it in simple terms, it seems like this can be an easy task to accomplish, no?

Just have a loop showing posts with the category of news on the front page and wrap that up with a `<marquee>` tag. I think that should work.

Comment: There should be a widget for adding posts. Additionally, you can selective iterate the **the loop** and choose #news and wrap that in a `<marquee>` but I haven't seen a `<marquee>` in a while!

Comment: haha. yea it worked. I wonder if there are better alternatives these days. A `<marquee>` definitely doesn't validate. I know there are javascript solutions. Maybe I can convince the client it's not worth it.

Comment: Yea, don't lower your standards. Your website says you make "standards compliant" websites. `<marquee>` is not-standard. (not meaning to stalk or anything, haha)

Comment: You've got to make something in jQuery that is not _constantly_ moving. Convince the client that constant movement is distracting to the user and the end result is to please the user.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a jQuery plugin for this. I saw one a while ago. As Jason said, don't make it move constantly. Move, pause for a while, then move again. Maybe fade in/out instead of move. Your client might think the fading effect is cooler!

Comment: @Jason: So true. I'll definitely bring it up to them. Thank you!